# How to get the prediction probabilities using cross validation in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I am using **`RandomForestClassifier`** as follows using cross validation for a binary classification (class labels are `0` and `1`).

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score

clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")
k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
accuracy = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'accuracy')
print("Accuracy: " + str(round(100*accuracy.mean(), 2)) + "%")
f1 = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = 'f1_weighted')
print("F Measure: " + str(round(100*f1.mean(), 2)) + "%")
```

Now I want to order my data using prediction probabilities of class `1` with `cross validation` results. For that I tried the following two ways.

```py
pred = clf.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
print(pred)

probs = clf.predict_proba(X)
best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:,-6:]
```

I get the following error

> **NotFittedError**: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted
>   yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

for both the situations.

I am just wondering where I am making things wrong.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case, you want to use the CV model for a unseen data point/s, use the following approach.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")

cv_results = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=3, return_estimator=True)

clf_fold_0 = cv_results['estimator'][0]

clf_fold_0.predict_proba([iris.data[133]])

# array([[0. , 0.5, 0.5]])
```

Comment: please let me know your thoughts on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636500/how-to-rank-the-instances-based-on-prediction-probability-in-sklearn

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) it specifies that the probability is calculated based on the mean results from the trees.

In your case, you first need to call the `fit()` method to generate the tress in the model. Once you fit the model on the training data, you can call the `predict_proba()` method.

This is also specified in the error.

```py
# Fit model
model = RandomForestClassifier(...)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Probabilty
model.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am using `cross validation` as well. just wondering how I can include `cross validation` with `predict.proba`. please let me know your thoughts. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using the following code:

```
proba = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, method='predict_proba')
print(proba[:,1])
print(np.argsort(proba[:,1]))
```