# How to rank the instances based on prediction probability in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I am using sklearn's support vector machine (`SVC`) as follows to get the prediction probability of my instances in my dataset as follows using `10-fold cross validation`.

```py
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

clf=SVC(class_weight="balanced")
proba = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=10, method='predict_proba')

print(clf.classes_)
print(proba[:,1])
print(np.argsort(proba[:,1]))
```

My expected output is as follows for `print(proba[:,1])` and `print(np.argsort(proba[:,1]))` where the first one indicates the *prediction probability of all instances for class `1`* and the second one indicates the *corresponding index of the data instance for each probability*.

```
[0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.2 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.9 1.  0.7 1.
 1.  1.  1.  0.7 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.9 0.9 0.1 1.
 0.6 1.  1.  1.  0.9 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.4 0.9 0.9 1.  1.  1.  0.9
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.9 0.
 0.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.  0.  0.8 0.  0.1 0.  0.1 0.  0.1
 0.3 0.2 0.  0.6 0.  0.  0.  0.6 0.4 0.  0.  0.  0.8 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]

[  0 113 112 111 110 109 107 105 104 114 103 101 100  77 148  49  48  47
  46 102 115 117 118 147 146 145 144 143 142 141 140 139 137 136 135 132
 131 130 128 124 122 120  45  44 149  42  15  26  16  17  18  19  20  21
  22  43  23  24  35  34  33  32  31  30  29  28  27  37  13  25   9  10
   7   6   5   4   3   8  11   2   1  38  39  40  12 108 116  41 121  70
  14 123 125  36 127 126 134  83  72 133 129  52  57 119 138  89  76  50
  84 106  85  69  68  97  98  66  65  64  63  62  61  67  60  58  56  55
  54  53  51  59  71  73  75  96  95  94  93  92  91  90  88  87  86  82
  81  80  79  78  99  74]
```

My first question is; it seems like `SVC` does not support `predict_proba`. Therefore, is it correct if I use `proba = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=10, method='decision_function')` instead?

My second question is how to print the classes of prediction probability? I tried `clf_classes_`. But, I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'classes_'`. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Note: I want to get the prediction probability for all the instances using cross validation.

**EDIT:**

The answer of @KRKirov is great. However, I do not need `GridSearchCV` and only want to use normal `cross validation`. Therefore, I changed his code use `cross_val_score`. Now, I am getting the error `NotFittedError: Call fit before prediction`.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: What is your end goal? what do you mean by ranking instances? `decision_function` can be used to rank, but it's not probability estimate

Comment: @ShihabShahriar I want to get the top predictions of the classifier. For example the top 200 predictions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross_val predict is a function which does not return the classifier (in your case the SVC) as part of its output. Therefore you don't get access to the latter and its methods and attributes.

To perform cross-validation and calculate probabilities use scikit-learn's GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV. If you want just a simple cross-validation, pass a parameter dictionary with only one parameter. Once you have the probabilities you can use either pandas or numpy to sort them according to a particular class (1 in the example below).

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

parameters = {'kernel':(['rbf'])}
svc = SVC(gamma="scale", probability=True)
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, cv=10)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

probabilities = pd.DataFrame(clf.predict_proba(X), columns=clf.classes_)
probabilities['Y'] = iris.target
probabilities.columns.name = 'Classes'
probabilities.head()

# Sorting in ascending order by the probability of class 1. 
# Showing only the first five rows.
# Note that all information (indices, values) is in one place
probabilities.sort_values(1).head()
Out[49]: 
Classes         0         1         2  Y
100      0.006197  0.000498  0.993305  2
109      0.009019  0.001023  0.989959  2
143      0.006664  0.001089  0.992248  2
105      0.010763  0.001120  0.988117  2
144      0.006964  0.001295  0.991741  2

# Alternatively using numpy
indices = np.argsort(probabilities.values[:,1])
proba = probabilities.values[indices, :]

print(indices)
[100 109 143 105 144 122 135 118 104 107 102 140 130 117 120 136 132 131
 128 124 125 108  22 148 112  13 115  14  32  37  33 114  35  40  16   4
  42 103   2   0   6  36 139  19 145  38  17  47  48  28  49  15  46 129
  10  21   7  27  12  39   8  11   1   3   9  45  34 116  29 137   5  31
  26  30 141  43  18 111  25  20  41  44  24  23 147 134 113 101 142 110
 146 121 149  83 123 127  77 119 133 126 138  70  72 106  52  76  56  86
  68  63  54  98  50  84  66  85  78  91  73  51  57  58  93  55  87  75
  65  79  90  64  61  60  97  74  94  59  96  81  88  53  95  99  89  80
  71  82  69  92  67  62]

# Showing only the first five values of the sorted probabilities for class 1
print(proba[:5, 1])
[0.00049785 0.00102258 0.00108851 0.00112034 0.00129501]
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I also want to get the corresponsing index of the probability. Earlier I took it as `np.argsort(proba[:,1])`. Since, the code got changed, I am not sure how to obtain that data. Please let me know your suggestions :)

Comment: Moreover, I also want to perform cross validation as I have done in my code. It would be greatly appreciated if you could add that too :)

Comment: What do you mean by getting the corresponding index of the probability? The iris data set has three classes (here encoded as 0, 1, 2) and therefore the classifier outputs three columns of probabilities - one for each class. If you sum the probabilities along each row their sum is 1 as it should be for probabilities.

Comment: cross_val_predict returns only a numpy array o.f predicted classes. If you want to do cross-validation and have a classifier and best parameters as an output use scikit-learn's GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV.

Comment: See the updated answer with GridSearchCV in place of cross_val_predict.

Comment: thanks a lot for the details. I updated my question by describing the index issue I have using `np.argsort(proba[:,1])`. Moreover, I would like to perform a simple cross validation first. In that case, is it correct if I changed `GridSearchCV` to `cross_val_predict`? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Final update from me. I hope this settles the matter. You can of course apply rounding to the probabilities to get them in a format that suits you.